# How can I force Docker Compose to rebuild containers when dockerfile changes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to start 2 containers using the following **docker-compose.yaml**.

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  myservice1:
    container_name: mycontainername
    build: 
       context: .
       dockerfile: ./my-dockerfolder/Dockerfile
       args:       
       - MY_ARG=${MY_ARG}
    environment: 
       - MY_ARG=${MY_ARG}
    mem_limit: 3500M
    ports:
    - "9090:9090"
    extra_hosts:
    - "one.mydomain.net:127.0.0.1"
    - "two.mydomain.net:127.0.0.1"


  myservice2:
    container_name: myothercontainername
    build: 
       context: .
       dockerfile: ./other-dockerfolder/Dockerfile
       args: 
       - BUILD=${BUILD}
       - MY_ARG=${MY_ARG2}
    environment: 
       - MY_ARG2=${MY_ARG2}
    ports:
    - "2023:22"
```

My problem is that when I run **docker-compose up** again, it is using the same image to create the container, regardless of changes to the docker file.

How can I force it to take changes to the docker file into account?

Are other docker objects being reused that I need to be worried about?  I want the second time I run **docker-compose up** to be as clean an environment as the first time.

note: I do not want to delete images that I do not need to delete.  I have a slow connection to the docker repo, and removeing all the images would make my **docker compose up** take ~22 minutes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Why not `docker-compose build` ?

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/

You can also do `docker-compose up --build` to force a rebuild.

Comment: Also worth noting that even if you build every time, Docker's built in cache means the image will only be rebuilt if you change the Dockerfile or any files that you are COPYing.

Comment: This does NOT force a rebuild, at least not when no files have changed.

Comment: hint: you can use parallel option to make it faster `docker-compose build --no-cache --parallel`

Answer (score 12):

I've found sometimes I need `docker-compose build --no-cache` if I have a bad deploy.

Comment: I think this should be the answer as it actually rebuilds, despite cache, which is what led me to find this Q&A

Comment: I agree. depends on why `docker build` is not a way to "fix" anything. That just assumes everything is working as normal.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Use this command:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that worked for me was to remove all images and then recreate all images.

Step 1. This will remove all images

`docker-compose down --rmi local/all`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

Step 2. This will create all images as part of up

`docker-compose up --build`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/